# Detox test not opening app, error: `role=testee not connected, cannot fw action`

Tags: react-native, detox

I've added detox to our project and configured it following the documentation. I have set permission for clearText as documented in https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/Introduction.Android.md#problem-the-app-loads-but-tests-fail-to-start-in-sdk--28 but I am still receiving the same error. I have tried running the example tests from the Detox project on my machine and it's working fine. I've compared all configuration between the two projects and I'm positive it's the same. The only thing that strikes me as odd, is that the app is not even being launched when I get the error. Y'all have any clue on what the issue could be?

Answer (score 1):

Solved: In the end it was a generic error related to a crash happening on the native side. Turns out that it was related to SOloaderand [this](https://github.com/facebook/SoLoader/issues/55#issuecomment-653890808) fixed the issue. :D